# Automating PDF Generation in VB.NET using a report in ACCESS 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, export-to-pdf

I've got a VB.NET application that automates PDF files runtime generation using a report in Microsoft  Access 2010.

This solution works fine on different computers but on station with Windows 7 and Office 2010 generates an error "Can't save the output data to the file you've selected."

Windows7 and Office are both genuine, registered and updated with last patch.

Everything works fine except this:

```
objAccApp.DoCmd.OutputTo(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "", 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Constants.acFormatPDF, myFullName, False, , ,                                            
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint)
```

This line gives me an error that I lead back to the Access run-time error:

"Can't save the output data to the file you've selected."

This is error only raise when I try to save in PDF format or XPS format.

If I change acFormatPDF to acFormatRTF it works fine.

I've read many threads on argument and none helped me for solving. I tried many suggestions, but did not work.

Steps Verified:

1. Rights on writing folder are correct (my user belongs to Administrators Group)
2. Create an empty pdf file with the same name, just before the command. This for trying to rewrite, but nothing to do.
3. Configured Office applications to run under a specific user account

The same problem happens if i use Access 2010 in interactive mode with the same report and same data.
When i click on ribbon "PDF o XPS" button  and after i write the file name will generate the same error, but if i try to print on Adobe Distiller works fine.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: In strange cases like this, I always make sure that no other software, most notably AV software, interferes with the process.

Comment: Sounds like it's something environmental in the office/access setup on that particular machine.  Maybe try an office repair?

Comment: Tried with repair and with remove and install Office 2010. Nothing to do.

Comment: Update: Remove Office 2010, 
Deleted Path on disk C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT OFFICE
Cleaned Registry finding and deleting all keys contains "MICROSOFT OFFICE".
Reinstalled Office 2010

I presume that it's a problem of permissions on some folder but i don't understand where it can be.

Same thing, same problem

Comment: Update2: Add New Administrator User but same result.